# Bluetooth HC-05 Library for Proteus

Tags: programming

I m working on a project in which I am using HC04 module so can anyone give me any Arduino Library for Proteus which have HC05 in it. Or tell me how to use HC05 in Proteus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this [Bluetooth Library for Proteus](http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2016/03/bluetooth-library-for-proteus.html). Thanks for helping me out guys. I am posting it here so that others can also get benefit out of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Proteus, but I think HC05 a bluetooth module? If so, the module interface from HC05 <==> arduino is done through Serial (UART) communication. 
Arduino has built in support for this - you don't need any special libraries besides SoftwareSerial.
wire up the module as such:
[image]

Then run the following code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define rxPin 10 // connected to TX pin of HC05
#define txPin 11 // connected to RX pin of HC05

SoftwareSerial mySerial(rxPin, txPin); // RX, TX
char bt; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   
  Serial.println("Hello");

  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.println("World");
}

void loop(){
  while(mySerial.available()){
    bt = mySerial.read();
    Serial.print(bt);
  }

  while(Serial.available()){
   bt= Serial.read();
   mySerial.print(bt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Proteus Library for HC05. (Not one I know of.)

Now, your HC05 is a serial device i.e. it acts as a **Serial monitor**. and fortunately there is **Serial Monitor** in Proteus. You can use that.

[Here, Have a look.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwViKGjCO2Y)

P.S. if you are using ISIS 7.x. there is a thing to be noted. You have placed a **serial monitor** and connected to arduino and you started execution and its working fine. Now, what happens sometimes is that when you stop execution and start again, serial monitor might not work. No need to worry about. Stop execution, delete that serial monitor and place a new.That will work.